# I cant change space between bullet points in css

Tags: html, css, tumblr

```
ul, ol, li { list-style-position:inside; margin: 33px 0; }
```

This code effect also my meny, footer on posts. Why is this happening and how to only effect bullet points and decimal?

Preview: http://sindreolsson.tumblr.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your menu and other items in your design are list items `li` as well, so with the rule you applied, those items will also receive a margin. You need to be more specific if you only want to have the bullet points in your text to have more margin. In your case, you could for instance want something like: I only want list items that are inside a tumblr post (`.tumblr-post`) to have a bigger margin. In CSS that would look like this:

```
.tumblr-post li {
  margin: 33px 0;
}
```

Don't forget to remove the margin from your own CSS. So, change

```
ul, ol, li { list-style-position:inside; margin: 33px 0; }
```

to

```
ul, ol {list-style-position:inside;}
```

EDIT: it seems you want this:

```
.tumblr-text li {
  margin: 33px 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, that worked for the meny, it still effect tumblr-footer. What is the best alternative for li in html? Should I use something else?

Comment: I've deleted my answer as I didn't understand the question. Glad you were able to help

Comment: @Sindre The **only** valid option directly inside an *ol* or *ul* element is an *li*. There is no alternative. You just need to realise that a style applied generically to the element type will apply to **all instances** of that element. By creating **more specific** styles as in Bram's answer, you can apply different styles to different instances of the element based on their parent (or parents) - thus allowing you to adapt each use of the element as needed for your design. This is exactly how CSS is designed to work.

Comment: @pwdst ok, thank you for your information! I managed to not effect the meny with Brams solutuion. It still effects tumblr-footer, anny solution? I think it is because tumblr-footer is a part of tumblr-post?